# How to make Three.js FOV responsive to height AND width?

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, responsive-design, viewport-units

## Background

I size everything using viewport units:

```
body {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) / 2);
}

h6 { 
  font-size: 1em;
}

div { 
  width: 20em;
}
```

As the number of pixels in the screen increases, so will the size of units. For example, a 1920 x 1080 display will have smaller type than a 2560 x 1080 display. This allows automatic support of ultra-wide, vertical, and high DPI (8k or even 16K) displays without media queries.

## Problem

Using Three.js, object scale responds only to the height of the screen. The object will appear the same size on a 1920x1080 monitor as it is on a 2560x1080 monitor. This is because Three.js camera uses a vertical field of view (FOV).

**Default Behaviour** - 2560x1080 compared to 1080x1080. Notice, *the text becomes smaller, but the 3D object stays the same size*. [**codepen example**](https://codepen.io/KMK_/pen/JzQMrg)

[image: 2560x1080]
[image: 1080x1080]

## My Attempt

The reason Three.js only responds to height is because it uses a vertical-fov. I tried to change the vertical-fov to diagonal-fov using this formula I found on stackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49356536/11268890).

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
var distance = 1000;
var diag = Math.sqrt((height*height)+(width*width))
var fov = 2 * Math.atan((diag) / (2 * distance)) * (180 / Math.PI);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov , width / height, 1, distance * 2);
camera.position.set(0, 0, distance);
```

The resulting behavior is the opposite of what should happen.

- On a smaller screen the [object becomes larger.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRRq4.png)
- On a larger screen the [object becomes smaller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEVeU.png)

#### current results

Objects in Three.js only become larger when increasing the viewport height. I attempted to modify the default vertical-fov to a diagonal-fov. However, this did not work.

#### desired results

When the viewport is resized, the object should change perceived size based on the formula ((viewport height + viewport width) / 2). This will ensure and text placed on the page remains the same relative scale to 3D objects. I would like to achieve this by altering the camera, instead of the 3D objects themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a scale ratio based on the width or height of the screen. For example:

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

if(SCREEN_WIDTH > {something} && SCREEN_WIDTH < {something}){
    camera.fov = SCREEN_WIDTH / {something}; //This is your scale ratio.
};

//Repeat for window.innerHeight or SCREEN_HEIGHT.

if(SCREEN_HEIGHT > {something} && SCREEN_HEIGHT < {something}){
    camera.fov = SCREEN_HEIGHT / {something}; //This is your scale ratio for height, it could be same as window.innerWidth if you wanted.
};

//Updating SCREEN_WIDTH and SCREEN_HEIGHT as window resizes.

window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false); //When window is resized, call onResize() function.

function onResize() {
    SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth; //Re-declaring variables so they are updated based on current sizes.
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight; //Camera aspect ratio.
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); //Updating the display
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) //Setting the renderer to the height and width of the window.
};
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you still have any questions

-Anayttal